# angular-select2 module implementation with ionic 3 app generating an error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic3

I am trying to implement angular-select2 npm module with my ionic 3 app.

1. I have installed the module through npm into my project
2. I have imported package to my **app.module.ts** file
3. I have declared `<select2>` tags into my application's html file

while running project with ionic serve command, it generates following error

[image: Error log on console]

Comment: please add the error directly.. image is not loading

Comment: Module build failed: Error ENOENT: no such file or directory open 'F:\MyApp\nod_modules\angular-select2-componenet\index.js' at error (native)

Comment: Please provide the component where you are importing it.

Answer (score 0):

Also try with importing package in yourPage.module.ts file with ,

```
schemas : [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```